# RewriteRule does not work, while the rest do

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, blogs, permalinks

My blog's .htaccess is setup in such a way that one page is accessed through multiple URLs, and displays different content depending on which URL is visited.

```
http://kn3rdmeister.com/category/blog/
http://kn3rdmeister.com/2012/
http://kn3rdmeister.com/2012/07/
```

all are actually using `http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog.php`.

The .htaccess file is very handy in the sense that I only need to redirect to one page (pretty much *ever*) just with different query strings. After a lot messing around with 'em, all of my rules finally work, and I'm dang glad that they do. Well, *almost* all of them work. The last one does not.

the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /category/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/blog/?$ blog.php [L]

RewriteRule ^category/blog/page/?$ /category/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/blog/page/([0-9]*)/?$ /category/blog/?pagenum=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1&month=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(^/]+)/?$ /category/blog/?url=http://kn3rdmeister.com/$1/$2/$3/$4/ [L]
```

The last rule is supposed to redirect to the "permanent link" page for each blog post. Being that each URL is unique, I'm using the post URLs as the unique identifier. Essentially, it is supposed to pass the "url" query string through "blog.php". The PHP script takes over, sees that the "url" query string is set, and then loads the only post with that exact URL in it's row.

The script works, but the redirect doesn't. Going directly to

`http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog.php?url=http://kn3rdmeister.com/2012/07/04/amsterdam-ave/`

will load the right content. However, going to

`http://kn3rdmeister.com/2012/07/04/amsterdam-ave/`

doesn't.

Comment: Hi, your website is vulnerable to SQL and/or XSS/CSRF exploit. Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry, missed yr comment so my A was too late.  Never mind.  Why not see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261963/1142045 for a simple way of avoiding doing your head in :-)

Comment: Thank ya very much TerryE, I'll be visiting that page :P Most often when I'm posting on here it's around 2AM and I'm not quite 100% there

Comment: When you're adding a comment and replying to someone who is not the poster of the Q or the A, then stick an @ in front of their username (tab completion works) and this trigger a message in their inbox. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [QSA (Query String Append)](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA). Also, invert rules so that "deeper" links go on top.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(^/]+)/?$ /category/blog/?url=http://kn3rdmeister.com/$1/$2/$3/$4/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1&month=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/?$ /category/blog/?year=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**But**, you can't use rewritten links in other rules. So wherever you have `category/blog/` replace it with `blog.php`.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting a 404 error. I'm going to creating a separate page for the "permalink" pages, I believe I'm starting to overuse blog.php to the point where I don't know what the heck is going on :)

Comment: kn3rdmeister, you've made a fool of yourself once more. Careful inspection reveals that I forgot a left bracket, "[", in the rule that would not work. Good day, gents.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst webarto comments are good advice, your problem is a missing [:

```
^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/?$
```

not

```
^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(^/]+)/?$
```